# Why is my classic ASP page loading twice?

Tags: html, asp-classic

I've got a classic ASP website and for some reason, if you view a full page load in FireBug, you'll notice that it actually has two separate HTTP GET's.

[Here's the page](http://www.brightminds.co.uk/crafts-for-kids/craft-kits/christmas-activity-pack.htm)

I've pulled the code to pieces and seriously can't find anything. Any suggestions would be very gratefully received!

Thanks

Comment: That is to a regular .html page...  I turned on FB and did not see anything load (no GET's).

Comment: It's a pseudo html page that's mapped to an ASP page via ISAPI ReWrite (essentially mod_rewrite). See this link for where the page loads twice.[link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/339/damnthing.jpg/)

Comment: @user739979 - I'll be honest, I would have to see the code and the behavior to see what is going on.  I haven't seen this behavior happen with just simple ASP.  Are you using AJAX maybe there are multiple calls?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

There was an IMG with a SRC="" that gets its SRC injected using javascript. So the browser was making two requests for the page. I replaced SRC="" with a default blank image and it's all now fine.

Thanks for your help!